# How to enable personalization and edit configuration in IIS for web parts in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-parts

I was trying to create a `web part` and I followed all the steps that are given in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk23dydw(v=vs.140).aspx)

**The problem:**
I get below error displayed in my browser after executing that `web part`.

> Personalization is not enabled and/or modifiable. The Enabled property must be set to true, and a registered personalization provider must be selected. The current user must be granted the right to modify personalization state.

I tried to find the solution in google so I found below link related to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178183(v=vs.140).aspx)

But, I am unable to understand that what how should I "edit configurations" as specified in link till now.

Could anyone explain me to resolve this problem?